# Distributed transaction across remote REST services implemented with Spring Boot using Atomikos trasaction manager

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jta, distributed-transactions, atomikos

I have need for two REST services that are part of the single transaction(distributed transaction), so if for example, client calls SERVICE_1 that is successful, and then SERVICE_2 that is not successful, SERVICE_2 **AND** SERVICE_1 must perform rollback.

I successfully achieved that with Atomikos transaction manager (TransactionEssentials), services implemented with Apache CXF, and Java client (transaction orchestrator) that calls  REST services with JAX-RS. I based my work on great examples provided by Atomikos, that can be found here: https://www.atomikos.com/downloads/extreme-transactions/com/atomikos/examples/5.0.6/examples-5.0.6-project.zip (examples-jta-rest-jaxrs).

The problem that I am facing is that when I replace REST services implementation with **Spring Boot**, the global transaction doesn't work any more. I narrowed the problem down to Spring Boot REST service that doesn't return 'Atomikos-Extent' attribute in the header that is required by the caller(that begins and commits global transaction). This is the exception that caller throws:

```
WARNING: Invalid extent found - any remote work will time out and rollback.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected an extent but found none. The remote work will not be committed by us.
      at com.atomikos.remoting.DefaultExportingTransactionManager.addExtent(DefaultExportingTransactionManager.java:70)
```

**So, the question is, how to implement Spring Boot REST service, so that it can participate in global transactions with Atomikos transaction manager.**

Bellow are some code snippets that could be important.

Client/caller

```
Client client1= newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class)
        .register(ParticipantsProvider.class)
        .register(TransactionAwareRestClientFilter.class);
Client client2 = //same as client1
UserTransactionManager utm = new UserTransactionManager();
utm.init();
utm.begin();
callService1();
callService2();
utm.commit();
utm.close();
```

Service

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAtomikosExampleApplication {
    //..    
    @Bean(initMethod="init", destroyMethod="close")
    public AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSource() {
        AtomikosDataSourceBean ds = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();   
        //..
        return ds;
    }
}

@Transactional
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test() throws Exception {   
        TransactionManager tm = new UserTransactionManager();
        tm.begin();
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement s = con.createStatement();) {
            s.executeQuery("select count(*) from menu");
        }
        tm.commit();
    }
}
```

I found vague information that with spring boot you should use Atomikos ExtremeTransaction instead of TransactionEssentials, but I am not sure if that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

- `com.atomikos.remoting.spring.rest.TransactionAwareRestContainerFilter`
- `com.atomikos.remoting.spring.rest.TransactionAwareRestClientInterceptor`

classes?

`TransactionAwareRestClientFilter` is under jaxrs package.

Comment: I tried using those classes, but as far as I can tell the latest version of Spring, uses version 4.0.6 of Atomikos, and those classes are not present in that version. They are available in com.atomikos transactions-remoting 5.0.6, and this library is not present in 4.0.6. I didn't figure out how to use atomikos 5.0.6 with latest version of spring. Is it possible that it is available only in TransactionsExptreme (paid version)? Any suggestions?

Comment: @zoran if you are using spring boot, then you are probably using BOM (version alignment) as well. Are you using maven or gradle as a build system? Try this resources:
Maven: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent

Gradle: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-customizing

Try to override the managed versions.